# How can I bring back my Android full screen keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, preferences

I have an app that that has worked from android 1.5 through 4.0.  Android 4.1 causes a problem with a simple EditTextPreference.  The app is always in landscape mode.  When I bring up the Team Name it looks like this.

[Pic 1 http://myweb.midco.net/hgs/s1.jpg](http://myweb.midco.net/hgs/s1.jpg)

Then when I click the Edit Text Field it has always looked like this.

[Pic 1 http://myweb.midco.net/hgs/s2.jpg](http://myweb.midco.net/hgs/s2.jpg)

But in my emulators and from a complaint on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 with Android 4.1 I get this.

[Pic 1 http://myweb.midco.net/hgs/s3.jpg](http://myweb.midco.net/hgs/s3.jpg)

This crushes the text field.  Changing the manifest to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

has not helped.  Leaving the Title blank does take the title off but you still cant see the edit text.  Here is the code for this Pref.

```
EditTextPreference teamnamePref = new EditTextPreference(this);  
teamnamePref.setTitle("Team Name"); 
teamnamePref.setKey( "t" + Team_ID );
teamnamePref.setSummary(TheTeamName); 
teamnamePref.setDialogTitle("Enter Name For Team " + Team_ID);
teamnamePref.setDefaultValue(TheTeamName);
teamnamePref.getEditText().setSingleLine(true);
TeamCategory.addPreference(teamnamePref);
```

Thank you

Comment: I guess you are using Pinyin IME on the emulator, change the keyboard to Android Keyboard and check

Comment: I dont see a way to change the keyboard in the eclipse emulator.  However, this result is in line with complaints I have received from users of my app.

Answer (score 1):

I created a method to work around this bug (tested on Samsung Galaxy S3, Acer A501 and HTC Desire X):

```
// This method provides a work-around for a bug with EditTextPreference and the Samsung soft keyboard.
// When in landscape mode, the Samsung keyboard can obscure the text box, as it does not use fullscreen 
// / extract mode like other keyboards do in this case.  So we manually show an alert dialog with an
// EditText control, and update the preference value manually.
//
// Usage:
// Create a normal <Preference> in your XML file, then in your corresponding fragment, retrieve the 
// preference object using its key and pass it to this method. E.g.
//
//    EditTextPreferenceHelper.CreateEditTextPreferenceDialog(
//         getActivity(), 
//         findPreference("yourPrefKey"));
public static void CreateEditTextPreferenceDialog(final Context context, Preference preference) {
    preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle(preference.getTitle());
            final EditText textBox = new EditText(context);
            textBox.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            textBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT);
            textBox.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(preference.getKey(), ""));

            builder.setView(textBox);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                            context).edit().putString(preference.getKey(), 
                            textBox.getText().toString()).commit();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
            return false;
        }
    });        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job. You can always modify the soft input flag to something else, like adjustPan. The reason this didn't work before for you is that EditTextPreference overrides those options.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class CustomEditTextPref extends EditTextPreference
{
    public CustomEditTextPref(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state)
    {
        super.showDialog(state);
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```